# Output Excel worksheet with special characters to CSV

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, export-to-csv, xlrd

I have an Excel file with multiple worksheets. I want to take a specific worksheet from the file and save this as a CSV file, delimited by commas ( I haven't gotten this far as yet). The worksheet contains data with special characters similar to last column on the right below. I don't mind ignoring these characters.

```
    **DateStamp Country ComputerName    Domain    IPAddress   OperatingSystem**
    2017-05-24  USA     Computer1       Domain1   1.2.3.4     Windows 2008
    2017-05-24  England Computer2       Domain2   1.2.3.5     Windows Server® 2008
```

My code so far is:

```
import os
import xlrd
import sys

file = 'path/to/my/file.xlsx'
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Data')

for rowx in range(sheet.nrows):
    coldata = sheet.row_values(rowx)
    coldata = " ".join(str(x) for x in coldata).encode('ascii')
with open ('/path/log.txt','a') as results:
    results.write(coldata)
results.close()
```

I am having to convert the data to string as otherwise it will include the **u'** next to each field, which i dont want in my CSV. On trying to do that I am encountering various errors.
The error I am getting is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If i try to ignore the characters, i land up with this:

```
colsdata = colsdata.decode('ascii','ignore')
Attribute error: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

These errors take place before I am able to write to the log.

Please may I get some assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. It will ignore the unicode characters that it can't convert.

```
import os
import xlrd
import sys
import unicodedata

workbook_path = "path/to/my/file.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(workbook_path)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
csv_data = ""

def normalize(value):
     result = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", unicode(value)).encode("ascii","ignore")
     return result

for rowx in range(sheet.nrows):
    coldata = sheet.row_values(rowx)
    # Append data to string that we are going to output
    # and add new line
    csv_data += ", ".join(normalize(x) for x in coldata) + "\n"

with open ("/path/log.txt","a") as results:
    results.write(csv_data)
```

I tested it with an excel file that had some bogus data and the text Windows Server 20008 ® and it returned the following for csv_data:

```
print csv_data

foo, bar, baz
1.0, 2.0, 3.0
4.0, 5.0, 6.0
7.0, 8.0, Windows Server 2008
```

Comment: Thanks, but only the last line is being written to the file? Even if I print coldata before I write to file, its only one line of data. And also it's not delimited, where would I specify that?

Comment: I've updated the code. You should be aware that the example above could be memory intensive if your excel file is really big. In that case you may want write directly to the file.

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you! Matter of interest, please can you explain what the normalise function does with reference to "NFKD"?

Comment: I refer you to [Python Unicode Graceful Degradation to ASCII](https://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/python-unicode-graceful-degradation-to-ascii/) for an explanation. Basically, it means replace compatible characters with their equivalent first.